# Зависание сайта

Tags: php

У меня сайт зависает. Из-за чего может быть? `http://bekzat.ueuo.com/` - вот мой сайт.

Comment: А как же ему не зависать? http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fbekzat.ueuo.com%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Дальше смотреть не стал, глаза заболели, исправляйте ошибки.

Comment: Проблем с доступностью сайта не наблюдаются. Все html-страницы генерируются нормально. Скорее всего связанно с использованием внешних ресурсов.

Comment: Скорее всего, у вас запускаются какие-то скрипты, из-за которых возникают тормоза. А вот откуда они запускаются - разобрать сложно. То ли js, то ли flash.

Comment: @bekzat, Опишите проблему более подробно. Что за CMS вы используете, какой мощности сервер, при каких условиях зависает и т. д.

Answer (score 4):

Во-первых, картинки. Например, та что в шапке - ее нужно обрезать под размер шапки, зачем еще невидимый кусок подгружать?

Во-вторых, видимо плеер постоянно на сервер обращается к файлу song.php и в ответ получает ошику 404 - это нехорошо.

В-третьих, в стилях

```
background-image:url('http://content.foto.mail.ru/bk/bek030694/_myphoto/i-10.jpg');
background-image:url('http://www.zastavki.com/pictures/1024x768/2011/3D-graphics_Fighters_in_the_sky_033108_.jpg');
```

картинки грузятся с других сайтов, сохраните картинки у себя.

Comment: +100500 Верно сказал.